# Use of Order by clause in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0

When creating table in cassandra, we can give clustering keys with ordering like below.

```
Create table user(partitionkey int, id int, name varchar, age int, address text, 
   insrt_ts timestamp,
 Primary key(partitionkey, name, insrt_ts, id)
 with clustering order by (name asc, insrt_ts desc, id asc);
```

when we insert data into that table, As per cassandra documentation records are sorted based on clustering keys.

When i retrieve records with CQL1 and CQL2, I am getting in the same sorted order.

CQL1:

```
Select * from user where partitionkey=101;
```

CQL2:

```
Select * from user where partitionkey=101 order by name, insrt desc, id;
```

what is the difference between CQL1 and CQL2?

Comment: Your clustering columns are the same as your ORDER BY in your CQL2 statement.  Why would you expect the results to be ordered differently between the two statements?

Comment: So there is no use of mentioning the order by clause if we want the values in the clustering keys order. when i query records with different order i'm getting an error. May i know what are all the other ordering i can do with above clustering keys?

Answer (score 6):

DataStax recommends a query-oriented data modeling approach, where the results are stored in the order in which they are required at query-time.  This order is determined by both the partition key and first clustering column of a [compound] primary key.  The [DataStax doc on the `ORDER BY` clause](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/select_r.html) explains this:

> Querying compound primary keys and sorting results ORDER BY clauses
>   can select a single column only. That column has to be the second
>   column in a compound PRIMARY KEY. This also applies to tables with
>   more than two column components in the primary key. Ordering can be
>   done in ascending or descending order, default ascending, and
>   specified with the ASC or DESC keywords.
>
> In the ORDER BY clause, refer
>   to a column using the actual name, not the aliases.
>
> For example, set
>   up the playlists table, which uses a compound primary key, insert the
>   example data, and use this query to get information about a particular
>   playlist, ordered by song_order. As of Cassandra 1.2, you do not need
>   to include the ORDER BY column in the select expression.

So basically you can really only alter it by asking for ASCending or DESCending order.

You also might want to check out the (free) Java development with Apache Cassandra online class at [DataStax Ac*ademy](http://datastaxacademy.elogiclearning.com).  I believe session 3 offers a module on the `ORDER BY` clause.

**Edit 2019**

For all future Googlers, I wrote an article on this topic about a year after this post.  It's older now, but still relevant to result set ordering with Cassandra: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order

Comment: So queries are ordered in the way we define clustering keys while creating the tables. If we want to reverse the order, only that time we have to give order by clause with desc. Thanks for the explanation.